# Scraping price data from Bloomberg using XPATH

Tags: html, xpath

Trying to scrape pricing data from this page: https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/EQUPEUI:LN

Using the following XPATH: /html/body[@class='default-layout markets-section-front']/div[@class='container']/main[@id='content']/div/div[@class='quote-page module']/div[@class='basic-quote']/div/div[@class='price-container up']/div[@class='price']

Not working... I am stuck and would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are so very close. You are just missing `/text()` at the end of your XPath expression.

```
/html/body[@class='default-layout markets-section-front']/div[@class='container']/main[@id='content']/div/div[@class='quote-page module']/div[@class='basic-quote']/div/div[@class='price-container up']/div[@class='price']/text()
```

This works in python:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

req = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/EQUPEUI:LN')
tree = html.fromstring(req.content)

price = tree.xpath("//div[@class='price-container up']/div[@class='price']/text()")[0]

print "The price is:", price
```

Note you can greatly simplify the XPath expression by not starting from the root HTML tag.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following relative xpath

```
//main[@id='content']//div[@class='price']
```

Locate the element with above xpath and use getText() method to get text of the element.